# Java Final Variables

Tags: java, variables, final

Can final variables be assigned to another variable?

```
final int a = 10;
```

Can I later assign that final varaible to another variable like:

```
int b = a;
```

Seems like java doesn't like it when I do that, but from what I understand final variable can only be assigned once. However in my case I am not assigning variable `a` anything instead I am assigning variable `b` the value of `a`.

Can someone englighten me about variable that are `final`? I've researched it on various websites but can't understand what was going on.

Comment: What you have shown is fine. What kind of problem are you seeing? A compiler error?

Comment: Are you sure? It should be fine to assign content of final variable to other variables.

Comment: Until you describe what "Java doesn't like it" means, this is not a real question.  Your understanding of final is correct, but this question is a straw man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and yes.  Final means the reference can't change; the value of the referenced object can.  Essentially, it is a modifier that applies to the variable name, not to the object itself.  When you declare `final Foo a = new Foo();` you are saying that `a` will always refer to the same object.  This is legal:

```
final Foo a = new Foo();
final Foo b = a;
b.setBar(5);
```

This is pretty much the only thing that isn't:

```
a = anotherFoo;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clearification. I was doing exactly the second thing you mentioned.